# Error running node application on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

We are trying to run node application on azure. It get deployed successfully but when we try to run the application we get following error in trace logs.

```
ActivityId  {A5FF0B34-7C3F-4A99-9497-6C04A9AE9A9F}
```

Message: iisnode was unable to establish named pipe connection to the node.exe process before the process terminated

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the node process crashed due to an exception in your nodejs code?

Comment: You can download the diagnostic logs via the KUDU api at `https://<your_site_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/dump`. And you can check the application logs in `\LogFiles\Application\` folder. And if it is convenient, it is great if you can provide your key code snippets of raising the server.

Comment: Get application logs using Gary's suggestion helped. Issue was with Azure env not understanding Babel commands like let etc.

Comment: Have you solve your issue? Or could you please specify your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gary's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842603/error-running-node-application-on-azure#comment57432981_34842603) worked.

> You can download the diagnostic logs via the KUDU api at `https://<your_site_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/dump`. And you can check the application logs in `\LogFiles\Application` folder.

After looking at logs, the issue was that Azure services couldn't understand babel syntax.

Tried another node app without Babel, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the solution above:

Check if the configuration setting WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION is set to the proper NODE Version.